# Is it possible to use something like MaxLength for Input Field of DatePicker?

Tags: wpf, datepicker

Is it possible to use something like MaxLength for Input Field of WPF DatePicker?

Comment: sure maxlenght=88 --> 01.04.2029 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DatePicker.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
       <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="10" />
    </Style>
</DatePicker.Resources>
```